# Would a theoretical Hulk be allowed to transform on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

This is *not* Purim Torah, but rather a thought experiment about Hilchos Shabbos.

Potentially, there are several Melachos that Bruce Banner violates in his transformation into the Hulk:

- Dyeing his skin, comparable to [those who prohibit tanning on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41104/)
- Tearing his clothing
- Growing (comparable to growing out one's nails, which begin growing three days after being cut; see [Mishnah Berurah 260:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.260.6))
- All of the destruction caused after his transformation; perhaps the transformation itself is forbidden in order to prevent damage from occurring after

The first two might be considered indirect (*gerama*), which might be entirely permissible, or direct but unwanted (*pesik reisha d'lo nicha lei*), for which there are certain leniencies.

The last two are entirely the purpose of the transformation, so at first glance it would seem that those should be forbidden entirely. However, it should be noted that, at least in most canons, the Hulk doesn't transform at will, but rather is tied to other stimuli, such as the time of day, or, more famously, his emotions. Therefore, perhaps it would depend on his intent: if Banner doesn't *want* to transform, getting angry would only be a *pesik reisha d'lo nicha lei*.

Is my reasoning correct? Would Banner's becoming angry on Shabbos be just a *pesik reisha d'lo nicha lei* at worst?

Comment: Dyeing his skin -- should be like the photo-gray lenses, just triggering what's already inside.

Comment: HULK MACHMIR NOT LIKE PUNY FEINSTEIN!!!

Comment: I also recently asked a Hulk related question! (Purim Torah tho) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100768/ptij-the-hulk-the-principle-of-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%93%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8-ie-whoever-is-stronger-prevai

Comment: @Shalom Seems to be the logic behind the opinion that tanning is fine, besides that it’s an unusual way of doing it. That’s why I specified that that point is only potentially valid according to the opinion that tanning is forbidden.

Comment: Maybe this is also why the kabbalists were so against getting mad on shabbos:)

Comment: @user6591 I was going to quote that, but while I’m aware it’s based on לא תבערו אש, I don’t know where it actually comes from.

Comment: Pretty sure it's from the Zohar.

Comment: Found this sourcing it to Tikunei Zohar https://dailyzohar.com/daily-zohar-401-3/

Comment: When did Bruce Banner acknowledge he was a Jew?  And (assuming he is Jewish)since the Hulk is a primitive, reptilian complex in charge form of human, does his foreskin grow back each time he transforms?

Comment: @Gary I don't think the comics address that...

Comment: To VTCers: Can you please explain why a halachic thought experiment is "bad subjective"?

Comment: Well -- an experiment is an experiment---starting conditions need to be defined...and does he need a mohel when he changes back or is that just automatically part of the process?  How many sets of tefillin does he go through, unless he has super-stretchy leather straps?  Can of worms opened...

Comment: @Gary Certainly there are other questions that can be asked about the Hulk once the can's been opened, which is why I limited it specifically to Hilchos Shabbos. Your Bris Milah question is an intriguing one; feel free to ask it separately, or I might steal it first. :)

Comment: "HULK NO HAVE FIANCEE DINAH!  N HULK MOHEL NEED CHAINSAW OR JIGSAW jNOT PUNY KNIFE...."